# non-duplicate entries of a line in text file

Tags: bash, unix, duplicates

How to display only non-duplicate word in the line of the text file using bash. For example, I have following lines in the text file:

```
1001 1002 1003 1002 1003
```

I want to display only 1001 . I don't want to display any word of the line which is duplicate.

I am trying

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/tmp/t1"

while IFS= read line
do
   echo $line | xargs -n1 | sort -u |xargs
done < "$file"
```

output is:

```
1001 1002 1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may se `awk` for this:

```
s='1001 1002 1003 1002 1003'

awk '{delete freq; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) freq[$i]++; 
for (i in freq) if (freq[i] == 1) print i}' <<< "$s"
```

```
1001
```

Answer (score 2):

a fix for your solution...

```
$ while IFS= read line; 
  do echo $line | 
     xargs -n1  | 
     sort       | 
     uniq -u    | 
     xargs; 
  done < file
```

**NB.** `uniq -u` and `sort -u` do different things.  Essentially `sort | uniq` equivalent to `sort -u`.  However `uniq -u` is only returning non repeated entries (complement is `uniq -d`)